# windows 10 how to get 'open file with' option?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

How do I get the option to choose to open the file with the non-default app in the File Explorer, (windows 10)?

When I double click on an html file it opens in my default app for that. But how do I get the option to choose to open the same file with a text editor? (Without changing default app)
Currently I only see 'Open' cut, copy delete & Properties.

Comment: It's either shift + right click or ctrl + right click, I can't remember which but try both. One should work

Comment: New Windows (old mac user). Mistake was : this does now work on files within zipped files. I wasn't aware that I was inside a zipped folder. Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Explorer, right click on the File and choose Open With. Since you have a default application, a dialogue box opens the allows you to select another app. Select "More apps" and see a selection as appears below

[image]

Comment: I never get the 'Open With' to begin with. I only get 'Open'.

Comment: If your right context is not working then run DISM and SFC to see if that fixes it. Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator and run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image /restorehealth followed by SFC /SCANNOW .  When done, restart and test.

Comment: You need to shift+right-click